# Convert htmlweb delegate from C# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates, html-agility-pack

I need to convert the [code found here](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/07/htmlagilitypack-set-timeout.html#.UHSy6pfNVvA) to its vb.net equivalent, what can I try?

Excerpt of the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the method that will handle the PreRequest event.
/// </summary>
public delegate bool PreRequestHandler(HttpWebRequest request);

    
//And they call that delegate right before making the GetResponse call:
if (PreRequest != null)
{
    // allow our user to change the request at will
    if (!PreRequest(req))
    {
        return HttpStatusCode.ResetContent;
    }              
}

HttpWebResponse resp;

try
{
    resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
    
//So all you have to do is assign a delegate to PreRequest and set your timeout within that delegate:

var web = new HtmlWeb();
web.PreRequest = delegate(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
{
     webRequest.Timeout = 4;
     return true;
};
var doc = web.Load("http://www.msn.com/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
''' <summary> 
''' Represents the method that will handle the PreRequest event. 
''' </summary> 
Public Delegate Function PreRequestHandler(ByVal request As HttpWebRequest) As Boolean


'And they call that delegate right before making the GetResponse call: 
If PreRequest IsNot Nothing Then
    ' allow our user to change the request at will 
    If Not PreRequest(req) Then
        Return HttpStatusCode.ResetContent
    End If
End If

Dim resp As HttpWebResponse

Try
    resp = TryCast(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
End Try

'So all you have to do is assign a delegate to PreRequest and set your timeout within that delegate: 

Dim web = New HtmlWeb()
web.PreRequest = Function(webRequest As HttpWebRequest)
     webRequest.Timeout = 4
     Return [True]
End Function
Dim doc = web.Load("http://www.msn.com/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://converter.telerik.com/ - paste in your C# code and get VB code back.